# Does it make sense to have unique_ptr for streams?

Tags: c++, c++11

Often I see `std::fstream`s passed by reference... but you can't copy them so if it's in a class, holding a reference to it seems finicky. In this case, I would prefer to use a `std::unique_ptr`. Which approach is better:

```
struct Handle
{
    Handle(std::string filename)
    {
        fstr.open(filename);
    }
    Handle(const Handle& o) = delete;
    Handle& operator=(const Handle& o) = delete;
private:
    std::ifstream fstr;
};
```

or:

```
struct Handle
{
    Handle(std::string filename)
        : fstr(std::make_unique<std::ifstream>(filename))
    {
    }
private:
    std::unique_ptr<std::ifstream> fstr;
};
```

Both forms prevent copying but the latter form takes less typing.

Comment: The copy constructor and copy assignment operator are already implicitly `delete`d in both cases, so `latter form takes less typing` is incorrect. I can't see any particular benefit in using the second example.

Comment: The second example adds a level of indirection and a heap allocation for no clear benefit. In other words, you sacrifice (an admittedly small amount of) performance for no reason.

Comment: And of course the constructor in the first one can further be simplified into `Handle(const std::string& filename) : fstr(filename) {}`

Answer (score 8):

In both of your examples, `Handle` actually subtracts functionality from `std::ifstream`.  It would be better to use `std::ifstream` rather than `Handle`.

The first example takes a *movable* `std::ifstream`, and makes it not movable.

The second example makes it movable again, but at the needless cost of an allocation.

Neither of your examples make it copyable (and they should not).

Just pass around `std::ifstream` in the same way that you would `std::unique_ptr<std::ifstream>` but without the clumsy pointer syntax.  `std::ifstream` is `MoveConstructible` and `MoveAssignable`.  You can just return it by value from factory functions or pass it into sink functions by value (if moved from) -- Just like `unique_ptr`.

Caveat:  gcc hasn't yet implemented moving streams so if that is the platform you are on, your second `Handle` has promise as a temporary workaround.